# Should web components be placed under "web" folder?

Tags: dart

Is the purpose to place web components under the `web` folder somewhere, or under the `lib` folder?

I'm asking because I'm unsure and it's not mentioned as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Put your components under the lib directory.

```
lib/
  control1.html
  control2.html
  control3.html
```

Let's say you configure your `pubspec.yaml` file and name your package 'my_controls'.

```yaml
name: my_controls
dependencies:
  html5lib: '>=0.3.1+2'
  web_ui: '>=0.3.2'
```

Since your project now defines a package, you can reference files in your lib directory as:

```html
<link rel="components" href="packages/my_controls/control1.html">
<link rel="components" href="packages/my_controls/control2.html">
<link rel="components" href="packages/my_controls/control3.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can point to components:

```
<link rel="components" href="component/ui/login.html">
```

in which case your components are in web/component/
and in web/component/ui/
you have the login.html file